# 0% hit rate with OPcache and PHP-FPM/Nginx

Tags: nginx, php, ubuntu-10.04, opcache

I'm trying to get PHP 5.5's OPcache working on an Nginx/PHP-FPM setup running on Ubuntu 14.04 in Vagrant.

I have my `/etc/php5/mods-available/opcache.ini` directory configured as follows:

```
zend_extension=opcache.so

opcache.enable=1
opcache.memory_consumption=256
opcache.max_accelerated_files=50000
```

Running `php -v` and `phpinfo()` shows that OPcache is enabled, and loading [opcache-status](https://github.com/rlerdorf/opcache-status) and [opcache-gui](https://github.com/amnuts/opcache-gui) shows the same.

In the OPcache GUIs I can see that files are being cached, and I've also confirmed this by setting OPcache to log in verbose mode. The problem is… they never get hit!

I've ran ApacheBench to hammer the application and not a single hit is registered - 0 hits and 103 misses. I've even tested a `hello_world.php` file which simply executes `echo 'Hello, world!';`, and that registers as a 'miss' every time too.

Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong?

**Update:**
I've managed to get a reproducible case of hits being registered. If, immediately after I run `service php5-fpm restart`, I run ApacheBench with 100 concurrent connections, the cache gets hit > 75%. From then on, each "normal" refresh will register as a hit, too.

However, if I restart php-fpm and my initial requests are "normal" (i.e. just from my web browser), and then I run ApacheBench with 100 concurrent connections - they all miss…

It's like the initial requests need to be hammering the server in order for hits to stick from then on… really bizarre! I'm assuming it might be to do with the way that php-fpm spawns processes but I'm really a novice in that area so if this gives anyone some clues - please help!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I've got a very different environment too you. I'm running apache and php with fast cgi without the process manager. Its getting a very low hit rate.

Comment: any news from this question?